# How make few views with same width

Tags: java, android, xml, android-linearlayout

I have code:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <ImageView
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <TextView
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <ImageView
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <TextView
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

When I try use this code, widths of left and right layouts is different.

I need create two LinearLayouts in row with same width.

If left layout have biggest width, then right layout must change width as left width. If right layout have biggest width, then left layout must change width as right width.

Parent layout must have layout_width="wrap_content", NOT "match_parent".

How I can do sizes of left and right layouts same?

Comment: I don't see why your code does not work, but nevertheless, I have a suggestion. There's a percent support library by Google, which allows you to set dimensions in percentages. Other possible solution is tranforming your code into RelativeLayout, with empty view to mark the center, and your LinearLayouts to start and end of that empty view.

Comment: When i change parent layout's properties layout_width="match_parent" my code work correct and both linearlayouts has same width, 1/2 of screen. But I need correct work without 'match_parent', when parent layout not have full width of screen...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Percentange Relative Layout][1]http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html

Answer (score 0):

On first `LinearLayout` you have missed line:

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

Add this and there will be no problems.

Comment: I have this line on head of my xml, I don't print this line for clear code

Comment: Then remove that parent `LinearLayout`.